# Are html5 notifications supposed to work if the page is not active?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, notifications

I have created a little app using html5 notifications but it appears those notifications don't work in some cases :

**Case 1** : I stay on the page. Notifications work.

**Case 2** : I switch to another app (alt+tab). Lst active page in Chrome is my app. Notifications work.

**Case 3** : I switch to another tab inside Chrome without closing my app. No notifications are shown until I switch back to app.

Is this a normal behaviour or am I running in some kind of bug? I could not found much documentation about it.

PS : Running Chrome on Centos 6 FYI

Answer (score 0):

The [Chromium API Specification](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) reads that

> If the page which generates a notification was generated is closed, the notification itself will not be closed, but events will not be delivered, as the script execution context is no longer present.

If that doesn't cover it, [this page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications) has more technical detail about how it is implemented in Chromium

Comment: Yes, I understand that if the tab is closed, but I'm not talking about a closed tab but an "active" tab, the current one.